# Spring Framework em projeto modular pelo Apache Maven

Tags: maven, spring, injeção-de-dependência

Eu criei um projeto web modular utilizando o Apache Maven com a seguinte estrutura:

```
proj-build
|--- proj-utils
|--- proj-persistence
|--- proj-services
|--- proj-web
`--- proj-ear
```

*Descrição*

**proj-build**: Este agrupa os módulos somente para a realização da build em cadeia nos módulos, isto é, cada projeto possui sua própria configuração quando é realizado o build, sem qualquer relacionamento com este projeto parent(proj-build).

**proj-utils**: Este módulo reúne classes utilitárias como: Classes Exceptions, Classes que configuram SessionFactory do Hibernate, etc..

**proj-persistence**: Este módulo reúne classes entidades, classes DAO, interfaces DAO. Possui dependências como JPA, Hibernate, etc..

**proj-services**: Este módulo reúne classes que implementam a lógica de negócio. Possui dependência do módulo proj-persistence.

**proj-web**: Este módulo reúne as classes Controllers, páginas HTML, CSS, Javascript e quaisquer outros recursos que necessitar nas páginas. Possui dependência com o módulo proj-services, Spring MVC, Spring Security, JSTL, Java Servlet, etc..

**proj-ear**: Este módulo tem dependência com todos os outros módulos exceto o proj-build. Este módulo empacota os outros módulos em um pacote EAR.

A minha dúvida é: Como eu aplico o Spring Framework DI/IoC como dependência neste projeto modular? Eu aplico a dependência em todos os módulos ou em algum módulo específico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As configurações do Spring podem ser distribuídas pelos projetos, cada uma configurando os seus respectivos componentes. Isso garante a possibilidade de testes unitários em cada módulo.

Alguns módulos vão ter dependências. Por exemplo, o `proj-services` provavelmente vai precisar  do `proj-persistence`, certo? Nesse caso há duas saídas:

## `Import` de configuração

A configuração de um projeto pode incluir a configuração de outro, simplesmente fazendo uma importação.

Imagine que você você tem um arquivo chamado `spring-config-service.xml` e esse projeto depende do `utils` e do `persistence`. Então na configuração deste projeto, faça assim:

```xml
<import resource="classpath:/spring-config-persistence.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:/spring-config-util.xml" />
```

## Inclusão via anotação em testes unitários

Outra alternativa (até mais flexível) é incluir as configurações apenas nos testes unitários.

Exemplo:

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:/spring-config-service.xml",
        "classpath:/spring-config-persistence.xml",
        "classpath:/spring-config-util.xml"})
@Configurable
public class UnitTests { ... }
```

No exemplo acima, pode-se ver que é possível acrescentar quantas configurações forem necessárias para inicializar o Spring no teste atual.

Isso é muito bom porque você poderia criar até configurações específicas para o teste, com *mocks* e tudo o que precisar, embora o mesmo pode ser alcançado usando *profiles*.

## Nota importante

Nos dois casos de importação o projeto deve declarar devidamente suas dependências do Maven e os arquivos de configuração devem estar nos seus respectivos diretórios `resource` para que estejam disponíveis no *classpath* de teste.

## Configuração da aplicação final

Finalmente, tratando-se de uma aplicação web que vai ser distribuída em um WAR, você pode definir todas as configurações que deverão ser carregadas com um parâmetro, assim:

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-config-web.xml
        classpath:/spring-config-service.xml",
        classpath:/spring-config-persistence.xml",
        classpath:/spring-config-util.xml"})
    </param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

Nota: se as configurações estiverem empacotadas em arquivos Jar e o Spring reclamar que não acha, tente adicionar um asterisco (`*`) após o termo `classpath` na definição, como no seguinte abaixo.

```xml
classpath*:/spring-config-util.xml
```

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado por me responder. E só para esclarecer, no primeiro caso que é sobre o módulo `proj-services`, em que é utilizado os `imports` para que seja possível injetar os DAO's e classes utilitárias no módulo `proj-services` pelo que eu entendi. Já no ultimo caso, que é a configuração do arquivo `web.xml`, é referenciado todos os arquivos de configuração de cada módulo, que é por onde o container tomará toda a configuração para interagir com todos os módulos como um todo, pelo que eu entendi. Me corrija se eu entendi errado.

Comment: (OBS.: no comentário acima o container que estou querendo dizer é o container de DI/IoC do Spring) Mas no caso dos arquivos `pom.xml` de cada módulo, estes terão a dependência do artefato `spring-context` certo? Com exceção do módulo `proj-web`, no qual este terá a dependência do `spring-mvc`, que de forma transitiva terá o `spring-context`.

Comment: @klaytonbrito Quanto ao primeiro comentário. Se você usar o import em um arquivo não precisa declarar todos no `web.xml`. Quanto ao segundo, você pode declarar o `spring-context` em todos mesmo, inclusive no web. Não é boa prática depender diretamente de dependências não declaradas. Para evitar redundâncias, use um *parent pom* com uma seção `dependencyManagement` que declare todas as dependências do projeto.

Comment: Entendi. Sobre o _parent pom_ é bom reaproveitar o `proj-build`? Ou é melhor criar outro módulo para dependências? Uma outra coisa, eu criei um `context.xml` que contém a configuração de um DataSource JNDI para conexão com banco de dados e coloquei no `META-INF` do módulo `proj-web` para que possa ser utilizado pelo Spring Security, mas o `hibernate.cfg.xml` que está no `proj-persistence` vai precisar apontar para o Datasource JNDI do context.xml, se eu utilizar essa propriedade assim irá funcionar corretamente? `<property name="connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/projbanco</property>`

Comment: O *parent pom* é melhor ser um projeto à parte, só para isso. Pelo menos para mim funciona melhor. Quanto ao *datasource* você pode configurar o Hibernate pelo Spring ([exemplo](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-4-spring)). Aí não repete a configuração.

Comment: Entendi, o link da configuração do Hibernate que você passou é bem interessante. Muito obrigado pela ajuda cara. Suas respostas me esclareceram muitas coisas e aprendi várias coisas novas.